# NameError when running in Flask App and not in flask shell

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I currently have a flask app and below is a snippit of code that works as it should:

```
from app import db  # sqlalchemy db

class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)
    ...

class ProducedItem(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('item.id'))
    item = db.relationship('Item',
                            primaryjoin=('Item.id == ProducedItem.item_id'))
    ...

class NewProducedItemForm(FlaskForm):
    items = [(i.id, i.name) for i in Item.query.order_by('name')]
    item = SelectField('Item', choices=items, coerce=int,
                        validators=[DataRequired()])
```

In the database I have two items and one produced item:

```
Item(1, corn)
Item(2, diadem)
ProducedItem(1, 1)
```

At this point, the application runs smoothly both in the flask shell and in the browser... in the flask shell I am able to do the following:

```
>>> items = [(i.id, i.name) for i in Item.query.order_by('name')]
>>> items
[(1, 'corn'), (2, 'diadem')]

>>> pitems = [(pi.item_id, pi.item.name) for pi in ProducedItem.query.all()]
>>> pitems
[(1, 'corn')]

>>> choices = [i for i in items if i not in pitems]
>>> choices
[(2, 'Diadem')]
```

However, when I do the following:

```
class NewProducedItemForm(FlaskForm):
    items = [(i.id, i.name) for i in Item.query.order_by('name')]
    produced_items = [(pi.item_id, pi.item.name) \
                        for pi in ProducedItem.query.all()]
    choices = [i for i in items if i not in produced_items]
    item = SelectField('Item', choices=choices, coerce=int,
                        validators=[DataRequired()])
    ...
```

and attempt to run the application (or the flask shell for that matter) the following exception is raised:

```
(venv) flask shell
...
stack trace
...
NameError: name 'produced_items' is not defined
```

I want the form to display items that are not produced_items. 
Can someone please point me in the right direction for resolving this issue?

Comment: 'produced_items' is a class attribute, it needs to be prefixed with (in this case) the class name.

Comment: @mechanical_meat even after putting `.all()` in the items query the same result it is produced. @Menno Hölscher what do you mean 'produced_items' is a class attribute? Both 'items' and 'produced_items' are declared in the same manner.